# Remove the first column of Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to remove the first column(the column used for selecting the row(s)) of the sap ui5 table.
I don't have the requirement to select the row(s).

I tried to do that by css, but, it is messing with the table alignment.

Can any one suggest, how to remove first column of table?

Comment: What about "TH" style?

Comment: "Th" style will not work in case of sapui5

Comment: Ok. But the answer from @Ngshumacher is very elegant.

Comment: that too does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `oTable.setSelectionMode(sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None)` if you want to disable row selection completely or `oTable.setSelectionBehavior(sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior.RowOnly)` if you want to be able to select a row by clicking on the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways.

```
table td:nth-child(1){ display:none;}
```

Works OK in Chrome + FireFox but not in IE

Use Jquery to handle cross platform issues using:

```
$('table td:nth-child(1)').hide();
```

works in all browsers!

---

Or if you have control of the html, you can:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">...</td>
    <td>..</td>
    ..
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can then create a css entry like:

```
table td.first { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table:Table id="toa__table"
                    enableSelectAll="false"
                    selectionMode="Single"
                    busy="{utilModel>/busy}"
                    selectedIndex ="1"
                    selectionBehavior="RowOnly"
                    rows="{path:'path' ,templateShareable:false}" >
```

use **selectionBehavior="RowOnly"** its hides first row ,and it work based selection mode Single or Multiple